# Drilldown query from SQL to DAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax, ssas-tabular

I have been thinking about moving some drilldown queries from T-SQL to DAX to improve performance. I have not really used DAX that much as a query language and was struggling to find examples that would let me convert the following simple SQL query. I have managed to find examples of [filtering tables](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-filtering-data/) and [joining tables](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-joining-tables/) but no real examples of combining these operations together in DAX.

The following query that I want to convert contains joining and filtering tables. Is it possible to rewrite this in DAX?

Another concern I have is that the column fp.[Fact Product Id] has a very high cardinality, really a degenerate dimension. When I tried rewriting this in MDX to run against the tabular cube, the query takes a long time and eventually blows up with out of memory errors. Will a DAX query suffer from the same problems?

```
Select dcpss.[Customer Product Status Rollup],
    dcpss.[Customer Product Status],
    dc.[Customer Id],
    dc.[Customer Name],
    dcps.[Customer Product Source],
    dp.Country,
    dp.[Product Number],
    dp.[Product Name],
    drbi.[Incident Number] As [Renewed By Order Number],
    drbi.[Incident Status] As [Renewed By Order Status],
    fp.[Fact Product Id] As [Product Id],
    fp.[Product Count],
    ded.[Date] As [Expiry Date]
From [rpt].[Fact Product] fp
    Inner Join [rpt].[Active Dim Product]  dp On dp.[Historical Product Key] = fp.[Product Key]
    Inner Join [rpt].[Active Dim Customer] dc On dc.[Historical Customer Key] = fp.[Product Customer Key]
    Inner Join [rpt].[Dim Expiry Date] ded On ded.[Expiry Date Key] = fp.[Expiry Date Key]
    Inner Join [rpt].[Dim Customer Product Source] dcps On dcps.[Customer Product Source Key] = fp.[Customer Product Source Key]
    Inner Join [rpt].[Dim Customer Product Status] dcpss On dcpss.[Customer Product Status Key] = fp.[Customer Product Status Key]
    Inner Join [rpt].[Dim Renewed By Incident] drbi On drbi.[Renewed By Incident Key] = fp.[Renewed By Incident Key]
Where ded.[Month of Year Name] = 'June'
    And ded.[Year Name] = 2015
    And (ded.[Day of Month] = @DayOfMonth Or @DayOfMonth Is Null)
    And dcps.[Customer Product Source] <> 'Free PP Product'
    And dc.[Payment Type] <> 'Free'
    And dp.Country = 'AU'
    And dp.[Sales Type] <> 'Trial';
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally worked this one out. I'm sure the query can probably be written better but using this [article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/best-practices-using-summarize-and-addcolumns/) here on projection and the [article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-filtering-data/) here on filtering showed how you can just use Summarize and the CalculateTable function.

Please note that this returns the distinct rows (no duplicates) which isn't a problem here as I am including the primary key field [Fact Product Id].

```
Evaluate
CalculateTable (
    Summarize(
        'Transactions',
        'Customer Product Status'[Customer Product Status Rollup],
        'Customer Product Status'[Customer Product Status],
        'Active Customer'[Customer Id],
        'Active Customer'[Customer Name],
        'Customer Product Source'[Customer Product Source],
        'Active Product'[Country],
        'Active Product'[Product Number],
        'Active Product'[Product Name],
        'Renewed by Order'[Incident Number],
        'Renewed by Order'[Incident Status],
        'Transactions'[Fact Product Id],
        'Transactions'[Product Count],
        'Expiry Date'[Date]
    ),
    'Expiry Date'[Month of Year Name] = "June",
    'Expiry Date'[Year Name] = "2015",
    'Expiry Date'[Day of Month] = Blank() || IsBlank(Blank()),
    'Customer Product Source'[Customer Product Source] <> "Free PP Product",
    'Active Customer'[Payment Type] <> "Free",
    'Active Product'[Country] = "AU",
    'Active Product'[Sales Type] <> "Trial"
)
```